# Getting SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException

Tags: java, android, sqlite

The issue is that I'm getting the SqLiteDatabaseCorrupException while executing the next code:

```
ArrayList<Advertiser> arr = new ArrayList<Advertiser>();
        Cursor holo = db.rawQuery("select * from Advertiser;", null);
        while(holo.moveToNext()){
            Advertiser adver = new Advertiser();
            adver.setId(holo.getString(0));
            adver.setNombre(holo.getString(1));
            adver.setDescripcion(holo.getString(2));
            adver.setDireccion(holo.getString(3));
            adver.setContacto(holo.getString(4));
            adver.setSitioWeb(holo.getString(5));
            adver.setFacebook(holo.getString(6));
            adver.setTwitter(holo.getString(7));
            adver.setPosx(holo.getDouble(8));
            adver.setPosy(holo.getDouble(9));
            adver.setCiudad(holo.getString(10));
            System.out.println("Objeto: " + adver.toString());
            arr.add(adver);
        }
```

What happens is that the while starts executing normally, but it gets to a point when the log cat shows that the database is corrupt and then the database gets eliminated.
Any reasons why this is happening?

EDITED:
I forgot to add, my application downloads the database when the main activity stars, does that has something to do with the database getting corrupted? The database is downloaded and stored on the sd card.

EDITED #2:
Here is the code of how I downloaded the database, hope that this helps:

```
public void DescargaBD() {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(
                "http://71.6.150.179:8079/dbHandler.axd?SqliteDbVersion=0");

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();

        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.connect();

        File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File file = new File(SDCardRoot, "DirLaguna.db");

        FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
        int downloadedSize = 0;

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bufferLength = 0;
        while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            downloadedSize += bufferLength;
        }
        fileOutput.close();
        location = file.getAbsolutePath();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `database eliminated` mean?  Does the database get deleted?  Is the database truly corrupt?  What happens if you manually perform a `select * from Advertiser` using sqlite3 from the command line?

Comment: Yes, the database gets deleted. I tried using the select * from Advertiser manually and everything works fine.

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed that this question had the android tag on it.  I need to research that.  I don't have any experience with sqlite on android.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022938/sqlitedatabasecorruptexception-database-disk-image-is-malformed

Comment: I followed the steps they suggest over there, still getting the error.

Comment: you said you are downloading database from server, r u sending only raw data or entire database. If you are sending database then try to open it in desktop (firefox sqlite plugin). r u able to open it?

Comment: Yes, I downloaded it first on my desktop to verify that the database link was working. I opened it with SQLite Database Browser and did some test querys and the database was working fine.

Comment: Could there be an issue in the code you use to copy or download the database to your client?  Could only a partial database get copied?

Comment: I'll edit my post to add the code of how I downloaded the database, but my guessing at the moment is that the problem is over there.